# How to get a list of key-combinations bound to (`stty`) terminal characteristics?

Tags: bash, terminal

> How to get a list of key-combinations bound to (`stty`) terminal characteristics?

I couldn't get forward search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) to work in Bash, so I searched the Internet and found that this key-combination is bound to XON/XOFF flow control (`stty [-]ixon`) by default. After disabling XON/XOFF flow control, forward search works.

How could I have identified that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> was bound to XON/XOFF flow control? More generally, how can I list all key combinations bound to (`stty`) terminal characteristics?

Comment: `stty -a` will tell you everything.

Comment: @UncleBilly - I see what you mean. `stty -a` lists `stop = ^S;`. How would I know `stop = ^S;` corresponds to `ixon`, so that I could quickly determine that I needed to execute `stty -ixon` in order to enable forward search (incremental)?

Comment: You go read `man termios` and that will tell you which flag enable which special chars (isig -> intr, quit, susp; icanon -> kill, erase; ixon -> stop, start; etc) and all the other intwractions. There's NO POINT in copy-pasting all that easily available info in an answer here.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, but I needed to know where to look in order to find this information.